# fscanf in while loop won't stop iterating

Tags: c, while-loop, scanf, fork

In a file I've got a huge amount of words (10.000) that I'ld like to work with "efficiently", so I've decided to divide them into chunks of 100 words distributed among a max amount of child processes (8) to avoid overhead, but my **while** statement for reading the file won't become false. Here is my code without the appropriate imports:

```
FILE* fp = fopen(argv[1], "r");
int index= 0;
int childs_amount = 0;

char* word = malloc(sizeof(char) * 46);  /* 45 is the len of the largest word in english */
char** words = malloc(sizeof(char*) * 100);  /* 100 is the amount of words I want to assign to a child */

while(fscanf(fp, "%s", word) == 1) {
    words[index] = malloc(sizeof(char) * 46);
    strcpy(words[index], word);
    index++;

    if (index == 100) {
        index = 0;
        pid_t child_pid = fork();
        if (child_pid == 0) {  /* Child process */
            usleep(5000);  /* do something */
            exit(0);
        } else {  /* Parent Process */
            childs_amount++;
            if (childs_amount == 8) {  /* 8 is the max amount of childs I want at the same time */
                pid_t ended_pid = wait(&status);  /* wait for any process to finish */
                childs_amount--;
            }
        }
    }
}
fclose(fp);
```

It's like my children processes are accessing it or maybe I should close the file before every **exit(0)**, but I really don't know, please help.

Comment: You seem to have forgotten to `fopen()` the file.  If that's not merely an artifact of posting the question here, then the behavior of your program is undefined.  If it *is* an artifact of posting the question, then please replace the code presented with a *bona fide* [mcve].

Comment: Sorry, the fopen() is included in my code, I'll update this.

Comment: I wrapped the code presented in the minimal adornment required to make it a complete program, and ran it on a 48000-word dictionary that happens to be present on my system.  It ran smoothly to completion, spawning one child process for each 100 words, just as seems to be the intent, and I don't see any reason to expect it to do otherwise.  Please, present a minimal, ***complete***, and ***verifiable*** example that demonstrates the problem, else we are unlikely to be able to help.

Comment: Could you share that minimal adornment please?, maybe I'll help me realize what's wrong with my code

Comment: I added all the necessary headers (stdlib.h, stdio.h, string.h, unistd.h, sys/types.h, and wait.h), made it the body of a standard `main()` function, and added a declaration of the undeclared `status` variable.  That's it.  Having shown that the program worked that way, I went on to add a little bit of output to prove that it was actually processing the file, and that worked, too.

Comment: Just eliminated the all of the `free()` statements for legibility

Comment: Eliminating the `free()`s is ok for the child-process code, and at the end of the main program, since you don't really need those anyway, but eliminating them from the post-fork parent process code introduces a moderately large memory leak.  This is likely to be counterproductive in the SO context, as the obvious leak will attract the attention of other respondants, and might even constitute a bona fide problem.

Comment: In any case, it would be a better simplification to just get rid of all the dynamic allocation altogether (you can easily use static arrays instead).

Comment: I solved this by adding an `fclose(fp);` before the `exit(0)` of the child's code. Thanks for your time

Comment: I'm glad you solved the problem, but when a process terminates, all its open files are closed automatically.  Not yet having seen an MCVE, I'm inclined to think that the true problem is somewhere else -- presumably, something producing undefined behavior.